PettingZoo MARL Forbidden Island Game --> ValueError: Output array has wrong dimensionality
I am working with PettingZoo MARL to make MultiAgent Model for playing ForbiddenIsland and I am getting this error with my observations.
Error
Below is the code for my observations:
def observation_space(self, agent):
        observation_space = gym.spaces.Dict({
            "position-x": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=7, shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
            "position-y": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=7, shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
            "tile_name": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=len(self.game.names), shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
            "hand": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=6, shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
            "current_class": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=len(get_random_classes()), shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
            "relics_acquired": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=3, shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
            "flood_level": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=500, shape=(1,), dtype=np.int64),
        })
        return observation_space

    def get_observation(self, agent):
        observation = {
            "position-x": agent.current_tile.pos[0],
            "position-y": agent.current_tile.pos[1],
            "tile_name": self.game.names.index(agent.current_tile.name),
            "hand": len(agent.hand),
            "current_class": agent.map[agent.player_class],
            "relics_acquired": len(self.game.clone().relics),
            "flood_level": self.game.clone().flood_meter[self.game.clone().flood_level],
        }
        print(observation)
        return observation

I've already tried a lot things such as formatting with numpy arrays with no such luck. However, maybe I did it incorrectly, so I'm open to suggestions.
